# How to use Chart.js with Typescript without getting assignable errors?

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm trying to use the library Chart.js in my Angular application with Typescript, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'stepSize' does not exist in type 'TickOptions'.
```

Looking at the `TickOptions` interface, the property is really not present there, but it's on another interface that extends `TickOptions`, the interface `LinearTickOptions`:

```
interface LinearTickOptions extends TickOptions {
    maxTicksLimit?: number;
    stepSize?: number;
    suggestedMin?: number;
    suggestedMax?: number;
}
```

How to make Typescript look for the interface `LinearTickOptions` instead of `TickOptions`?
This is the code that shows the error:

```
new Chart(this.clientsPerMonthElement.nativeElement, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels,
    datasets: [{
      data,
      label: 'Clientes no mês',
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      borderColor: lineColor,
      borderWidth: 2,
      pointBackgroundColor: lineColor,
      pointRadius: 4,
    }],
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepSize: 1, // I'm getting an error here
        },
      }],
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: can you post whole component code on how you import chartjs

Comment: @Sajeetharan, import * as Chart from 'chart.js';

Comment: I have exact same issue

Comment: Same issue here, anyone with solution for this. I can't build my project

Comment: @IvoBogoevski, I couldn't solve so I removed the type definition dependency for now.

Comment: @IvoBogoevski, It seems that updating everything to the latest version, the error is solved. Here it wasn't necessary to import LinearTickOptions as KaSSii answered.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue but I have found a solution for this

You will need to import the `LinearTickOptions` from 'chart.js' as well

```
import { Chart, LinearTickOptions } from 'chart.js';
```

You will then need to create a variable that holds this information

```
xAxisTickOptions: LinearTickOptions = {
  min: 0,
  stepSize: 0.02,
};
```

You will need to separate variables if the use X and Y with different step values (obviously)

from there we can go and just reference the variable in the options object

```
xAxes: [
       {
         type: 'linear', //optional
         ticks: this.xAxisTickOptions,
         ...
        }
      ]
```

Everything should resolve itself from there. My best guess at this reason is because the Axes implement `TickOptions | LinearTickOptions | ...` . So it will just grab hold of the first option unless you want to implement the whole LinearTickOptions interface in the tick object

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It seems that updating everything to the latest version, the error is solved. Here it wasn't necessary to import LinearTickOptions.